# meteor, using _.map when joining collections

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Here is my helpers to diplay data from two collections

```
Template.Lirescategorie.helpers({
    scategories: function () {
        var cursor = Scategories.find();
        var data = [];
        cursor.forEach(function(somewhat) {
            var categories = Categories.findOne({_id : somewhat.categorieID}, {categorie:1});
            data.push({cat : categories.categorie, scat : somewhat.scategorie });
        });
        return data;
    }

});
```

Here are my collections

```
categorie : 
{
  "_id": "LBKZQfZZSf4DRdeXo",
  "categorie": "Citoyenneté"
}
scategorie
{
  "_id": "cNHYpAEvC9ffjWkf5",
  "categorieID": "LBKZQfZZSf4DRdeXo",
  "scategorie": "Etat-Civil"
}
```

I'm pretty sure my helpers' code is not optimal. And i think by using _.map or something like that i can reduce the code.
Since i'm not really familiar to it, i'm looking for help about this.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: i want to use _.map, or something like that inset of forEach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to client-side joins. You can use `.map()` to get the list of `categorieID`s and do the second find in one go with `$in:`:

```
var cursor = Scategories.find();
var arrayOfCategorieIDs = cursor.map(function(s){return s.categorieId});
var categories = Categories.find({_id : {$in: arrayOfCategorieIDs}});
```

Then:

```
var sCategories = cursor.map(function(s){return s.scategorie}); // array of scategorie names
var categoryNames = categories.map(function(c){return s.categorie}); // array of categorie names

Then assemble these two arrays of strings into the array of objects you're looking for.
```

But there's a far simpler pattern for a client-side join: just iterate over one cursor and do the lookup into the related collection in a helper. For example:

html:

```
{{#each sCategories}}
  {{sCategorie}}
  {{categorie}}
{{/each}}
```

js:

```
Lirescategorie.helpers({
  sCategories:(){
    return Scategories.find();
  },
  categorie:(){
    return Categories.findOne(this.categorieID).categorie;
  }
});
```